# Trigger Error in SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I got a table named 'test' and there's 2 column in it : SKTEST and test2

I want to increment the SKTEST column at every insert on the table, so I've created a sequence and a trigger.

But I've encountered an error with my trigger sentence :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INCRSK
BEFORE INSERT ON schema.test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
     :new.SKTEST := SK_SEQUENCES.NEXTVAL
END
/
```

When I want to insert values in my column test2 from the table test :

```
INSERT ALL
INTO schema.test (test2) values ('10')
INTO schema.test (test2) values ('20')
INTO schema.test (test2) values ('30')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I got the following error :

> ORA-04098 : trigger 'User.INCRSK' is invalid and failed re-validation

So I've checked the error with the following sentence :

```
SELECT * FROM user_errors WHERE type = 'TRIGGER' AND name = 'INCRSK'
```

And it showed this :

> PLS-00103 : encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following : . ( * / etc

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Maxim Borunov it works !

Comment: 2 semicolons are absent 1) :new.SKTEST := SK_SEQUENCES.NEXTVAL; 2) end;

Comment: Oh right, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your trigger ddl two ';' symbols are missing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INCRSK
BEFORE INSERT ON schema.test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
     :new.SKTEST := SK_SEQUENCES.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```